# How get region from latitude and longitude using in Meteor js?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about to get region(city,state and country) from latitude and longitude using in Meteor js.Can you please suggest me what to do for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you define as a region? a rectangle? a state, precinct or county?

Comment: Region means city,state and country.@IanJones

Comment: This is called reverse Geocoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try make smth like this:

```
HTTP.call("get", "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=" + SOME_LAT + "&lon=" + SOME_LNG + "&addressdetails=1", function(error, result) {

  if (!error) {
      //parse result
  } else {
    throw new Meteor.Error("...");
  }
});
```

Response:

```
 {
   "place_id": "2573424409",
   "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright",
   "osm_type": "way",
   "osm_id": "330047765",
   "lat": "46.46377035",
   "lon": "30.73842925",
   "display_name": "1 к1, Волзький провулок, Odessa, Prymors'kyi Rayon, Odessa, Odessa Oblast, 65007, Ukraine",
   "address": {
        "house_number": "1 к1",
        "road": "Волзький провулок",
        "city": "Odessa",
        "county": "Prymors'kyi Rayon",
        "state": "Odessa Oblast",
        "postcode": "65007",
        "country": "Ukraine",
        "country_code": "ua"
    }
}
```

Comment: how to parse result.Can you please suggest me?@none

Comment: It's very easy. If you need country do `country = result.data.address.country;`, if you need something else - do the same: `state = result.data.address.state;` You have to do it in place `//parse result`

Comment: I get error as status code: 

{ statusCode: 429,
]content: 'Bandwidth limit exceeded</title>Bandwidth limit exceeded</h1>\n\n<p>You have been temporarily blocked because you have been overusing OSM\'s geocoding service or because you have not provided sufficient identification of your application. This block will be automatically lifted after a while. Please take the time and adapt your scripts to reduce the number of requests and make sure that you send a valid UserAgent or Referer.</p>\n\n<p>